# Does CSS transition work with positioned elements?

Tags: css, css-transitions

This time, I'll include the code (as I've been asked previously).
The problem is that, even when this code does what I need (a CSS modal/lightbox window), I can't get it to animate neither the top nor the translate properties.
I think it's a problem of positioning, because, the original example used no position for the container but, instead, used the :before pseudo-element (I don't like it).
What's wrong with this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Pure CSS Modal Window</title>
    <style>
        *
            {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            }
        .modal-container
            {
            position: fixed;
            display: none;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            right: 0px;
            bottom: 0px;
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
            }
        .modal-content
            {
            position: absolute;
            top: -100%;
            left: 50%;
            width: 70%;
            max-width: 400px;
            max-height: 400px;
            transform: translateX(-50%);
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            transition: all 5s;
            }
        .modal-container:target
            {
            display: block;
            }
        .modal-container:target .modal-content
            {
            top: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#modal1">Modal 1</a>
    <a href="#modal2">Modal 2</a>
    <div class="modal-container" id="modal1">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
            <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
            <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
            <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
            <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
            <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
            <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
            <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
            <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
            <a href="#modal-close">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-container" id="modal2">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <p>This is the content of Modal 2</p>
            <a href="#modal-close">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `display` state changes from `display: none` to `display: block`, meaning there is no previous layout to transition between.

One option would be to replace `display: none` with `visibility: hidden` and `display: block` with `visibility: visible`.

### Working Example:

```css
*
    {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    }
.modal-container
    {
    position: fixed;
    visibility: hidden;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    }
.modal-content
    {
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 70%;
    max-width: 400px;
    max-height: 400px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    transition: all 5s;
    }
.modal-container:target
    {
    visibility: visible;
    }
.modal-container:target .modal-content
    {
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
<a href="#modal1">Modal 1</a>
<a href="#modal2">Modal 2</a>
<div class="modal-container" id="modal1">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
        <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
        <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
        <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
        <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
        <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
        <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
        <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
        <p>This is the content of Modal 1</p>
        <a href="#modal-close">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-container" id="modal2">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <p>This is the content of Modal 2</p>
        <a href="#modal-close">Close</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander.
I had just entered to close this question because I found another answer. Your's is great as well, but I solved it just separating both DIV's.
I mean, instead of:
    <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    <p>Content here</p>
    </div>

And for the CSS I used .container:target + .content & it worked perfectly.

Thanks anyways. I'd use your tip for my future projects.
Marcelo.

Answer (score 0):

The solution provided by Alexander O'Mara works great (& also taught me a little), but I found another answer.
I solved it just separating both DIV's. I mean, instead of:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="content">
    <p>Content here</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I used:

```
<div class="container">
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p>Content here</p>
</div>
```

And for the CSS I used:

```
.container:target + .content {}
```

instead of

```
.container:target .content {}
```

All this without changing "display: none" for "visibility: hidden", as Alexander suggested, & it worked perfectly.
Thanks for your help. It's great to see that people around the world worries about other one's problems & try to solve them.

Cheers.
Marcelo.